# How to call and pass information to a Python script in a Laravel 9 project?

Tags: javascript, python, json, laravel, laravel-9

I have an HTML form in my Laravel 9 project saved to the browser's localStorage using JS (with jQuery). I also have a Python script that needs to take a CSV-formatted database, modify it based on the information from localStorage, and convert it to JSON. Lastly, I have a JavaScript file that takes the JSON and builds an HTML table. All of these parts work separately, but I'm having trouble integrating python into my Laravel 9 project.

What is the best way to call and pass information to a Python script within a Laravel 9 project?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mostly have 2 solutions, you either transform that phthon script into a webserver and laravel communicates with it like a microservice, super easy to do (communication), or you can use Symfony's Process to execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself. I did it like this:

1. Create a controller:

```
php artisan make:controller PythonController
```

2. Add a function to the controller. Here is one example:

```
    public function runScript()
    {
        $scriptFile = public_path('script.py');
        $command = "python $scriptFile";
    
        exec($command, $output, $status);
    
        return view('database');
    }
```

3. Update the routes in `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/run-python-script', [PythonController::class, 'runScript']);
```

Remeber to add: `use App\Http\Controllers\PythonController;` in the `web.php`

4. Make an AJAX request to run the Python script. Here done in JS with jQuery:

```
$.get('/run-python-script', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```